# Store a unique reference to a Mysql Table

Tags: mysql, sql, database, performance, database-design

I am creating a site that is sort of ecommerce-ish. I want to give my users a perfect search ability using specific attributes that differ from product to product. I plan to create 1 products table storing the basic information that is shared among products i.e Name, Description, Price and a few others. Then I plan to create several "details" table say categories_computers with columns Processor, HDD, RAM, etc and another table say table_shoes with columns MATERIAL, SIZE, GENDER, etc.

I am new to Mysql but not to the concept of Databases. I don't think I will have a problem storing this data to each table. My issue comes about from reads. It won't be hard to query a product id but I think it would be extremely wasteful to query all details tables to get the details of the product since 1 product can only have 1 details.

So my question is how can I store a reference to a table in a column so that a product has say ID, Name, Description, Price, Details_Table_ID or something similar to save on queries. Do tables have unique ids in Mysql? Or how does the Stackoverflow community suggest I go about this? Thanks.

**EDIT**

Silly me, I have just remembered that every table name is uniques so I can just use that, so my question changes to how I can write a query that contains one cell in a table A to be used as a reference to a Table name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use separate details tables for each category, use a generic details table that can store any attribute. Its columns would be:

```
Product_ID INT (FK to Products)
Attribute VARCHAR
Value VARCHAR
```

The unique key of this table would be `(Product_ID, Attribute)`.

So if `Product_ID = 1` is a computer, you would have rows like:

```
1   Processor   Xeon
1   RAM         4GB
1   HDD         1TB
```

And if `Product_ID = 2` is shoes:

```
2   Material    Leather
2   Size        6
2   Gender      F
```

If you're worried about the space used for all those attribute strings, you can add a level of indirection to reduce it. Create another table `Attributes` that contains all the attribute names. Then use `AttributeID` in the `Details` table. This will slow down some queries because you'll need to do an additional join, but could save lots of space

Comment: Thanks for the comment, but would there be more gains if I can be able to use a separate table? Such as specifying data and minimizing redundancy for example Shoes may only need 3 more columns but Computers might need 8 and so on.

Comment: The problem is that it becomes difficult to write general purpose queries for that architecture. Table and column names can't be specified in variables in SQL, so everything would have to be done with dynamic SQL.

Comment: Ok, I understand that part. So I believe I would have to mix Php and Mysql and would probably have to query the database twice. Such that the first query returns the basic details, which I would have to get the details_table_name and pass it as a variable to php and use that for my next query?

Comment: Yes. But how would you know what the columns are in the second table? You can use `SELECT *` to get all the columns, but what if you want to search for attributes with a specific value? How would you know what column names to put in the `WHERE` clause?

Comment: I plan to use Javascript for searching. The reason is that, when a user navigates to say mysite.com/category/computers then all the displayed products have similar search parameters. My major issue was how to efficiently read this data from the database. I will try it my way (that you helped me figure out) then compare performance. I will mark your response as the answer though, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Think about just having a single ProductDetails table like this:

```
ProductDetailID (PK)
ProductID (foreign key to your Products table)
DetailType
DetailValue
```

this way you do not have to create new columns every time you add a new product detail type. and you'll have many ProductDetail rows for each productid, which is fine and will query ok. Just be sure to put an index on ProductDetails.ProductID !

Comment: Thanks for the comment Rocky, but I was wondering whether I would have more benefits of using many separate tables as my comment above.

Comment: @DonOmondi Don't you think there's something going on when two of us independently made the same recommendation?

Comment: @Barmar I think it shows that there is the general accepted way of doing this, but I am here to ask if the way I think would be better placed to solve my specific application needs.

Comment: Having multiple tables will be bigger burden in the long run. Multiple tables requires significantly more coding and upkeep to keep track of the Product Details. For example, let's say you decide to add a new Detail. It's much simpler to add a row to an existing table instead of creating a new column or object.
You want to have a perfect searching experience for your users. Using a single table to track your Product Details will be much more efficient and faster. You just have to index on the ProductID and DetailType (or Attribute, as Barmar called it) columns and searches will be fast.

Comment: If you instead have multiple tables and columns, searches will be slower and harder to program because you'll have to query many objects. Querying just one properly indexed table will be significantly faster and easier. It's win-win: simpler design and faster searches.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an application so you must be generating the queries. So lets generate it in 2 steps. I assume you can add a column product_type_id in your Product table that will tell you which child table to user. Next create another table Product_type which contains columns product_type_id and query. This query can be used as the base query for creating the final query e.g.

Product_type_id  | Query

1                |  SELECT COMPUTERS.* FROM COMPUTERS JOIN PRODUCT ON COMPUTERS.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID

2                |  SELECT SHOES.* FROM SHOES JOIN PRODUCT ON COMPUTERS.PRODUCT_ID = PRODUCT.PRODUCT_ID

Based on the product_id entered by the user lookup this table to build the base query. Next append your where clause to the query returned.